# heatmap for gauge/indicator

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a collection of (sparse) data that has temperature measurements.  With a heatmap, areas that have more observations show a higher value because the heatmap accumulates the values.

Is there a way to get more of an average as opposed to a sum?  But also with the feel of gaussian filtering.  If no data is in a region, a 0 value would be preferred (which would be transparent).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to gaussian filter, see [ndimage.gaussian_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html)

Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage

fig = plt.figure()

# Random example data with some values set to 0
im = np.random.random((10, 10))
im[im < 0.3] = 0

# Smooth image
smoothed_im = scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter(im, sigma=1)

im[im == 0] = None
plt.imshow(im, interpolation = "nearest")
plt.title("Original image")
plt.colorbar()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(smoothed_im, interpolation = "nearest")
plt.title("Smoothed image")
plt.colorbar()

# Blank elements that were originally 0
smoothed_im[np.isnan(im)] = None
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(smoothed_im, interpolation = "nearest")
plt.title("Smoothed image with original zeros blanked")
plt.colorbar()
```

This produces:

[image]